# Version mismatch after update: How to find matching versions of dask and distributed?

Tags: python, distributed, dask

How can I figure out, which version of `dask` is compatible to which version of `distributed`?

Background: I updated dask using the conda package manager. In this process, distributed was updated as well. For debugging purposes, I now want to downgrade dask, however, using

```
conda install dask=0.11.1
```

does not downgrade `distributed`. Is this because distributed 1.14.3 is supposed to work with dask 0.11.1? Or - if not - how can I figure out, which version of distributed matches a certain dask version? Maybe I should use another conda command?

Comment: Ideally conda should yell at you here.  Dask/distributed specifies minimum version requirements for Dask: https://github.com/conda-forge/distributed-feedstock/blob/master/recipe/meta.yaml

Comment: I double checked that conda doesn't throw any error. Additionally, looking at  `dask.__version__` and `distributed.__version__` confirmed the version mismatch. Maybe conda only checks the [meta.yaml of the dask repository](https://github.com/conda-forge/dask-feedstock/commit/200efcb88984ba35849880b95ec0a112705104e0) during that process, where it finds the requirement `distributed >=1.11.0`, which is satisfied?